# Eclipse character encoding messed up in error message (cygwin turns ' into â€™?)

Tags: c++, eclipse, character-encoding, cygwin

I started to study c++ and i choosen Eclipse IDE for it.

I got a little issue, see picture here:

[image]

You can see the charaters are pritty messed up, how could i solve this issue?

I tried to set Elipse's character encoding to ISO and UTF from cp1250 but nothing happened, i think that error message comes from the c++ compiler (I use cygwin) itself or something like that.

Any advice?

**E D I T:**

I tried to set character encoding in cygwin terminal with:

```
set LANG=es_MX.UTF-8
```

Nothing changed.

Comment: did you try to change encoding to UTF-8

Comment: As i wrote, yes. But i think this message comes in exactly this form from the compiler itself, so maybe i should config the compiler but i dont know how.

Comment: Try to use MinGW instead!

Comment: I made big efforts to kept this working and now with this small but annoying bug should i just install MinGW instead? :-\

Comment: If it's a compiler issue and you can't figure it so just install MinGW

Comment: where did you set UTF-8 cause there is to places?

Comment: Window->Preferences->General ->Workspace->Text File Encoding
But thats just in eclipse, and i think i should do the character encodings set right in cygwin's g++, but i dont know how. I tried in cygwin's terminal with LANG command but not so much happened.

Comment: Try this Window->Prefrences->General->Editors->Text Editors->Spelling and set encoding to UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

Try to modify your debugger encoding settings:

[image]

Comment: Sadly not working but thanks all these efforts man i upvoted your answer, though it is not working. Maybe i should just install MinGW like you said :)